# Django Sphinx compilation error: index.rst not found and WARNING: Unknown directives

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I'm facing a weird mistake. Here I have a Django project that runs very well locally, I even generated the documentation and everything is going perfectly well.
The problem is that when I import the project in https://readthedocs.org/ the compilation fails, I tried almost everything, but always the same problem.

*I use Django == 2.2
Python == 3.7.8*

**My project structure:**

```
- Myproject
  -- docs
     -- build
     -- source
        - conf.py
        - index.rst
        - file.rst
        - another_file.rst
     make.bat
     Makefile
     requirements.txt
 -- MyprojectDir
 -- MyappDir
```

**My conf.py file inside my source directory look like this:**

```
# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
#
# This file only contains a selection of the most common options. For a full
# list see the documentation:
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html

# -- Path setup --------------------------------------------------------------

# If extensions (or modules to document with autodoc) are in another directory,
# add these directories to sys.path here. If the directory is relative to the
# documentation root, use os.path.abspath to make it absolute, like shown here.
#
# import os
# import sys
# sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))


# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------

import os
import sys
import django
cwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(cwd, '../../')))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'vtcvlp.settings'
django.setup()

from sphinx.ext.autosummary import Autosummary
from sphinx.ext.autosummary import get_documenter
from docutils.parsers.rst import directives
from sphinx.util.inspect import safe_getattr
import re


class AutoAutoSummary(Autosummary):

    option_spec = {
        'methods': directives.unchanged,
        'attributes': directives.unchanged
    }

    required_arguments = 1

    @staticmethod
    def get_members(obj, typ, include_public=None):
        if not include_public:
            include_public = []
        items = []
        for name in dir(obj):
            try:
                documenter = get_documenter(safe_getattr(obj, name), obj)
            except AttributeError:
                continue
            if documenter.objtype == typ:
                items.append(name)
        public = [x for x in items if x in include_public or not x.startswith('_')]
        return public, items

    def run(self):
        clazz = str(self.arguments[0])
        try:
            (module_name, class_name) = clazz.rsplit('.', 1)
            m = __import__(module_name, globals(), locals(), [class_name])
            c = getattr(m, class_name)
            if 'methods' in self.options:
                _, methods = self.get_members(c, 'method', ['__init__'])

                self.content = ["~%s.%s" % (clazz, method) for method in methods if not method.startswith('_')]
            if 'attributes' in self.options:
                _, attribs = self.get_members(c, 'attribute')
                self.content = ["~%s.%s" % (clazz, attrib) for attrib in attribs if not attrib.startswith('_')]
        finally:
            return super(AutoAutoSummary, self).run()


def setup(app):
    app.add_directive('autoautosummary', AutoAutoSummary)


project = 'vtc-video-link-post'
copyright = '2020, MBAMBA FABRICE DAMIEN'
author = 'MBAMBA FABRICE DAMIEN'

# The full version, including alpha/beta/rc tags
release = '1.0'
master_doc = 'index'
autosummary_generate = True

source_suffix = [".rst", ".md"]
pygments_style = "sphinx"

# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------

# Add any Sphinx extension module names here, as strings. They can be
# extensions coming with Sphinx (named 'sphinx.ext.*') or your custom
# ones.
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc', 'sphinx.ext.doctest',
              'sphinx.ext.intersphinx', 'sphinx.ext.todo',
              'sphinx.ext.ifconfig', 'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
              'sphinx.ext.inheritance_diagram',
              'sphinx.ext.autosummary',
              'recommonmark',
              'sphinx.ext.coverage'
              'sphinx.ext.ifconfig',
              'sphinx_autodoc_typehints',

              ]

# Add any paths that contain templates here, relative to this directory.
templates_path = ['_templates']

# List of patterns, relative to source directory, that match files and
# directories to ignore when looking for source files.
# This pattern also affects html_static_path and html_extra_path.
exclude_patterns = []


# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------

# The theme to use for HTML and HTML Help pages.  See the documentation for
# a list of builtin themes.
#
html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'

# Add any paths that contain custom static files (such as style sheets) here,
# relative to this directory. They are copied after the builtin static files,
# so a file named "default.css" will overwrite the builtin "default.css".
html_static_path = ['_static']
```

**When i compiling my document in https://readthedocs.org/ I get this error, but it install all requirements files**

```
Running Sphinx v3.2.1
loading translations [en]... done
making output directory... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [readthedocs]: targets for 5 source files that are out of date
updating environment: [new config] 5 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [ 20%] source/index
reading sources... [ 40%] source/intro
reading sources... [ 60%] source/launch
reading sources... [ 80%] source/usage
reading sources... [100%] source/vtcvlp

/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/vtc-vlp/checkouts/latest/docs/source/vtcvlp.rst:7: WARNING: Unknown directive type "autoclass".

.. autoclass:: vtcuser.models.CustomUser
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:

    .. rubric:: Methods

    .. autoautosummary:: vtcuser.models.CustomUser
        :methods:

    .. rubric:: Attributes

    .. autoautosummary:: vtcuser.models.CustomUser
        :attributes:
/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/vtc-vlp/checkouts/latest/docs/source/vtcvlp.rst:24: WARNING: Unknown directive type "autoclass".

.. autoclass:: vtcuser.models.VideoLink
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:

    .. rubric:: Methods

    .. autoautosummary:: vtcuser.models.VideoLink
        :methods:

    .. rubric:: Attributes

    .. autoautosummary:: vtcuser.models.VideoLink
        :attributes:
/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/vtc-vlp/checkouts/latest/docs/source/vtcvlp.rst:41: WARNING: Unknown directive type "autoclass".

.. autoclass:: vtcuser.api.CustomUserViewSet
    :members:
    :undoc-members:

    .. rubric:: Methods

    .. autoautosummary:: vtcuser.api.CustomUserViewSet
        :methods:

    .. rubric:: Attributes

    .. autoautosummary:: vtcuser.api.CustomUserViewSet
        :attributes:
/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/vtc-vlp/checkouts/latest/docs/source/vtcvlp.rst:57: WARNING: Unknown directive type "autoclass".

.. autoclass:: vtcuser.api.VideoLinkViewSet
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:

    .. rubric:: Methods

    .. autoautosummary:: vtcuser.api.VideoLinkViewSet
        :methods:

    .. rubric:: Attributes

    .. autoautosummary:: vtcuser.api.VideoLinkViewSet
        :attributes:
/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/vtc-vlp/checkouts/latest/docs/source/vtcvlp.rst:74: WARNING: Unknown directive type "autoclass".

.. autoclass:: vtcuser.serializers.CustomUserSerializer
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:

    .. rubric:: Methods

    .. autoautosummary:: vtcuser.serializers.CustomUserSerializer
        :methods:

    .. rubric:: Attributes

    .. autoautosummary:: vtcuser.serializers.CustomUserSerializer
        :attributes:
/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/vtc-vlp/checkouts/latest/docs/source/vtcvlp.rst:91: WARNING: Unknown directive type "autoclass".

.. autoclass:: vtcuser.serializers.VideoLinkSerializer
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:

    .. rubric:: Methods

    .. autoautosummary:: vtcuser.serializers.VideoLinkSerializer
        :methods:

    .. rubric:: Attributes

    .. autoautosummary:: vtcuser.serializers.VideoLinkSerializer
        :attributes:
/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/vtc-vlp/checkouts/latest/docs/source/vtcvlp.rst:109: WARNING: Unknown directive type "automodule".

.. automodule:: vtcuser.views
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/vtc-vlp/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/cmd/build.py", line 280, in build_main
    app.build(args.force_all, filenames)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/vtc-vlp/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 348, in build
    self.builder.build_update()
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/vtc-vlp/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 299, in build_update
    len(to_build))
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/vtc-vlp/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 311, in build
    updated_docnames = set(self.read())
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/vtc-vlp/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 422, in read
    self.env.doc2path(self.config.master_doc))
sphinx.errors.SphinxError: master file /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/vtc-vlp/checkouts/latest/docs/index.rst not found

Sphinx error:
master file /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/vtc-vlp/checkouts/latest/docs/index.rst not found
```

**Locally All work very well that's look at this:**

```
Running Sphinx v3.2.1
making output directory... done
[autosummary] generating autosummary for: index.rst, intro.rst, launch.rst, usage.rst, vtcvlp.rst
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 5 source files that are out of date
updating environment: [new config] 5 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] vtcvlp
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] vtcvlp
generating indices...  genindex py-modindexdone
highlighting module code... [100%] vtcuser.views
writing additional pages...  searchdone
copying images... [100%] capture4.png
copying static files... ... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in English (code: en)... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded.

The HTML pages are in build\html.
```

***Readthedoc errors log details: ---->>>>*** [The build log details](https://readthedocs.org/api/v2/build/11886281.txt)

***Where could I have made a mistake?***

Comment: You don't provide enough information for anyone to help you. Check the build log on RTD for details, or share a link to it.

Comment: Steve Piercy i have add it. Please i wait any positive comment.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm smashing my head on exactly the same problem....

Comment: @Davide_sd, Yes i have finally found solution

Answer (score 4):

For those who had the same issue, I had exacatly the same issue when RTD built from my github reop. I finally found that the reason was the wrong configuration of `conf.py` path in `.readthedocs.yaml`.

```
# File: .readthedocs.yaml

version: 2

# Build from the docs/ directory with Sphinx
sphinx:
  configuration: docs/conf.py
...
```

Actually, my `conf.py` located in `docs/source`, when I changed the last line as shown below, it worked as expected.

```
  configuration: docs/source/conf.py
```